# Using sed to change the second word after a constant

Tags: sed

This should be easy but I cannot seem to get the correct syntax down. 
I have a file containing the following line: 
host 'reg' 'PROC' 'admin' 'EIFEBJFFBOENGKGF'

host is unquoted and is the only constant. The other values that are qouted I will not know the exact value of.  What I want to do is replace the first word in single quotes, in this case 'reg' with a new value and leave the rest of the line as is.  I have tried a number of variations:

echo "host 'reg' 'NCO_PA' 'bsmadmin' 'EIFEBJFFBOENGKGF'"  | sed  "/host/s/['*']/'newvalue'/"

host 'newvalue'reg' 'NCO_PA' 'bsmadmin' 'EIFEBJFFBOENGKGF'

echo "host 'reg' 'NCO_PA' 'bsmadmin' 'EIFEBJFFBOENGKGF'"  | sed  "/host/s/[\'.\']/\'newvalue\'/"

host 'newvalue'reg' 'NCO_PA' 'bsmadmin' 'EIFEBJFFBOENGKGF'

It seems I am only getting it to replace the first sigle quote with the value. So my goal is to change

host 'reg' 'PROC' 'admin' 'EIFEBJFFBOENGKGF'

to

host 'newvalue' 'PROC' 'admin' 'EIFEBJFFBOENGKGF'

The value of the second field will be a hostname, so it might contain any charater that is valid for a hostname,  reg.test.com, reg-1.test.com, boo.radley.com, etc... surrounded by single quotes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "host 'reg' 'NCO_PA' 'bsmadmin' 'EIFEBJFFBOENGKGF'" | \
   sed "s/^host\s*'[^']*'/host 'newval'/"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/'\''[^'\'']*'\''/'\''new value'\''/' file
```

or:

```
new_value='a new value'
sed 's/'\''[^'\'']*'\''/'\''"$new_value"'\''/' file
```